# Content Will Only Display After Reload

Tags: vue-router, vuejs3, jscalendar

I'm attempting to display a simple calendar based on the [jsCalendar](https://github.com/GramThanos/jsCalendar) library. When I navigate to the page, the calendar won't appear; however, when I reload the page [⌘-R] or enter the page URL directly, the content appears normally. I've tested in Safari and FireFox and the behavior is the same.

##### Desired Outcome:

Display the content when the page is reached via Vue Router or direct navigation.

##### Calendar.vue

```html
<template>
    <div class="auto-jsCalendar black-theme"
         data-navigator-position="right"
         data-month-format="month YYYY"
         data-day-format="DDD">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import 'simple-jscalendar'

  export default {
    emits: ['page-data'],
    mounted() {
      this.$emit('page-data', {title: 'calendar', content: '',})
    },
  }
</script>

<style>
  @Import '~simple-jscalendar/source/jsCalendar.css';
  @Import '~simple-jscalendar/themes/jsCalendar.darkseries.css';
</style>
```

##### Navigating to Calendar.vue

When navigating to the page, the `div` looks like this:

```html
<div class="auto-jsCalendar black-theme" data-navigator-position="right" data-month-format="month YYYY" data-day-format="DDD"></div>
```

##### Reload or Direct Navigation

When reloading the page or entering the URL directly into the browser, the `div` looks like this:

```html
<div class="auto-jsCalendar black-theme" data-navigator-position="right" data-month-format="month YYYY" data-day-format="DDD" jscalendar-loaded="true"></div>
```

(The dynamic attribute `jscalendar-loaded` (which is added to the div when the calendar object is displayed) is not established when navigating to the page.)

[image: jsCalendar Output]

##### Environment:

```
Dave@[SNIP] my_spa % npm list
my_spa@0.1.33 /.../my_spa
├── @vue/cli-plugin-babel@4.5.15
├── @vue/cli-plugin-router@4.5.15
├── @vue/cli-plugin-vuex@4.5.15
├── @vue/cli-service@4.5.15
├── @vue/compiler-sfc@3.2.20
├── babel-eslint@10.1.0
├── chart.js@3.6.0
├── chartjs-plugin-annotation@1.1.0
├── chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0
├── core-js@3.19.0
├── eslint-plugin-vue@7.20.0
├── simple-jscalendar@1.4.4
├── vue-router@4.0.11
├── vue@3.2.20
├── vue3-smooth-dnd@0.0.2
├── vuex-persist@3.1.3
└── vuex@4.0.2
```

EDIT: In consulting with the author of jsCalendar, I've come to learn that the script acts on the page load event which explains why the content doesn't update when navigating to the view. The external script has an `autoFind()` function which could be called from `mounted()` which should update the content; however, I've been unable to find the right way to call the function.

```html
import jsCalendar from 'simple-jscalendar'

mounted() {
  jsCalendar.autoFind()
  this.$emit('page-data', {title: 'calendar', content: '',})
},
```

results in:

```
Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: simple_jscalendar__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.autoFind is not a function.
```

Comment: Could it be that this library has an on ready handler that initializes it when the page loads? Then I would try to call this init method in the mounted hook.

Comment: While it's most likely possible to write a wrapper to support this library (or fork it), that's beyond my skill set at the moment. Instead, I was able to find another terrific Vue 3 compatible library [v-calendar](https://vcalendar.io) that suits my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the documentation from the link, here is what I would do:
remove the `auto-jsCalendar` from the div as this is the hook that makes it work when you load the page, but not when you navigate and add a `ref`.
Then in your mounted hook call the `jsCalendar.new` as documented here:
https://gramthanos.github.io/jsCalendar/docs.html (Javascript Create Calendar)

```
<template>
    <div class="black-theme"
         data-navigator-position="right"
         data-month-format="month YYYY"
         data-day-format="DDD"
         ref="calendar">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import 'simple-jscalendar'

  export default {
    emits: ['page-data'],
    mounted() {
      jsCalendar.new(this.$refs.calendar)
      this.$emit('page-data', {title: 'calendar', content: '',})
    },
  }
</script>

<style>
  @Import '~simple-jscalendar/source/jsCalendar.css';
  @Import '~simple-jscalendar/themes/jsCalendar.darkseries.css';
</style>
```

Though in the long run I'd suggest to look for a library that was built for Vue. It is always a bit tricky if a third party library manipulates the DOM that is also used from Vue.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. Unfortunately, with this construction, I get a `Can't find variable: jsCalendar` error. So I changed the import to `import jsCalendar from 'simple-jscalendar' and I get a `new is not a function` error.  I'll continue to tinker with the API calls you referenced and see if I can land on something.  You may be right that this library (while pretty awesome) is ill suited to Vue.  Cheers.

Comment: That should be `new is not a function` error.

Comment: @DaveL17 there are other examples, maybe `new jsCalendar(this.$refs.calendar);` works

Comment: Yep, tried that too.  Results in a `object is not a constructor` error.